# WPF variable number of dragable objects that do not scale on resize

Tags: wpf, xaml, resize, draggable, itemscontrol

**The Problem**:

I have a non-fixed number of items to paint on a canvas with following requirement:

1. The items are *complex*: A circle with centered text, tooltips, some extra text arround.
2. The items may *change during runtime* (calls for `Binding`...)
3. The items have *coordinates* that need to be *scaled* to drawing coordinates (for example items with x coordinates in the range of from 500 to 5000 must be drawn on screen from 0 to 190)
4. The *items* itselves *must not resize when the containing `Canvas` resizes*. Only position of the item should resize.
5. For every item a horizontal and vertical *grid line* has to be drawn and the grid line has to be *labeld* at the axis.
6. The items should be *draggable*: The position should be *updated* in the underlying data.

I have a construction with `ItemsControl` which satisfis requirements 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 but I have no idea about how to get it draggable and it's became rather complex and ugly.

I tried it whith `ItemsSource` with each a `Canvas` as `ItemsPanel`, positioning the items with a `Style`, `Transforms` and `Converters`.

**The Questions:**

1. How could this be done in another way, especially without a `Style` in the `ItemsControl`?
2. How can I get my **items draggable**?

**My Code:**

(In my Code, the property `Points` is the `ObservableCollection` if the to be drawn items)

Items template (exmaple, selected with a `TemplateSelector`):

```xml
<DataTemplate x:Key="inactiveViewableControlPointTemplate" DataType="{x:Type stationary:ViewableControlPoint}">
    <Canvas LayoutTransform="{StaticResource horizontalFlipTransform}">
        <Canvas.ToolTip>
             <StackPanel>
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding PointString, StringFormat={}Point {0}}"/>
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Speed, StringFormat={}Speed: {0}%}"/>
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Load, StringFormat={}Load: {0}%}"/>
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding WeightsJoined, StringFormat={}Weigthingfactor: {0}}">
                      <TextBlock.Style>
                          <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                              <Style.Triggers>
                                   <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding WeightsJoined}"  
                                                Value="{x:Static sys:String.Empty}">
                                       <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                   </DataTrigger>
                               </Style.Triggers>
                           </Style>
                      </TextBlock.Style>
                 </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
         </Canvas.ToolTip>
         <Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" Fill="White">
             <Path.Data>
                  <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="20" RadiusY="20" Center="0,0"/>
             </Path.Data>
         </Path>
        <TextBlock Canvas.Bottom="0" Canvas.Left="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
            FontFamily="Helvetica" FontSize="10"
            stationary:Mover.MoveToMiddle="Both" Text="{Binding Path=PointString}"/>
        <TextBlock Canvas.Bottom="10" Canvas.Left="20" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
            FontFamily="Helvetica" FontSize="9" FontStyle="Italic"
            Text="{Binding Path=WeightsJoined}" Background="#7fff"/>
    </Canvas>
</DataTemplate>
```

The items (Points) `ItemsControl`, child of a general `Canvas`:

```xml
        <ItemsControl Name="pointItems1" Canvas.Top="0" Canvas.Left="0"
                      ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource PointTemplateSelector}"
                      ItemSource="{Binding Points}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas Width="{Binding ElementName=stationaryUI, Path=Width}" Height="{Binding ElementName=stationaryUI, Path=Height}">
                    </Canvas>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ResourceKey=PositionTransformXConverter}">
                                <Binding ElementName="stationaryUI" Path="DataContext.Transform"/>
                                <Binding Path="X"/>
                                <Binding Path="Y"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ResourceKey=PositionTransformYConverter}">
                                <Binding ElementName="stationaryUI" Path="DataContext.Transform"/>
                                <Binding Path="X"/>
                                <Binding Path="Y"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ItemsControl>
```

The `PositionTransformConverters` apply the transform and return either a `Double` or a `Point`. The `Transform` is held in the resources, could also be part of the `DataContext`'s *ModelView* object.

The grid lines are painted with:

```xml
       <ItemsControl Name="verticalLinesItems"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Speeds}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas Width="{Binding ElementName=stationaryUI, Path=Width}" Height="{Binding ElementName=stationaryUI, Path=Height}" >
                    </Canvas>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Line Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeEndLineCap="Square">
                        <Line.X1>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource PositionTransformXConverter}" ConverterParameter="v X1">
                                <Binding ElementName="stationaryUI" Path="DataContext.Transform"/>
                                <Binding Path="Position"/>
                                <Binding Source="0"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Line.X1>
                        <Line.Y1>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource PositionTransformYConverter}" ConverterParameter="v Y1">
                                <Binding ElementName="stationaryUI" Path="DataContext.Transform"/>
                                <Binding Path="Position"/>
                                <Binding Source="0"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Line.Y1>
                        <Line.X2>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource PositionTransformXConverter}" ConverterParameter="v X2">
                                <Binding ElementName="stationaryUI" Path="DataContext.Transform"/>
                                <Binding Path="Position"/>
                                <Binding Source="100"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Line.X2>
                        <Line.Y2>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource PositionTransformYConverter}" ConverterParameter="v Y2">
                                <Binding ElementName="stationaryUI" Path="DataContext.Transform"/>
                                <Binding Path="Position"/>
                                <Binding Source="100"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Line.Y2>
                    </Line>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

`Speeds` is a `Property` with only a `get` that iteerates over my Points items singles out duplicate entries in the x-axis. A comparable property exists for the y-axis. The labes are drawn like the grid lines, only with text instead of lines.

On `Canvas` **resize**, the `Transform` is **updated** and all `ItemsControls` repaint.

Comment: Is it possible for you to narrow down the question to the concerned issue only? perhaps with the issue description, location etc and smallest reproducible example only.

Comment: I updated the text. I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: When you were asked *Is it possible for you to narrow down the question to the concerned issue only?*, @pushpraj did *not* mean *Can you please add even more content to your already long question?* Your question is too long and you should follow the advice in the [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) page on MSDN for further information on how to shorten it.